# Which MongoDB approach is better for code readability and scalability?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a MongoDB document called `User` with the following model:

```
var User = mongoose.schema({
   _id: ObjectId,
   name: String,
   age: Number,
   blog_posts: [ObjectID]
});
```

and a document called `BlogPost` with the following model:

```
var BlogPost = mongoose.schema({
   _id: ObjectId,
   title: String,
   author: ObjectId,
   content: String,
   date: Date
});
```

Now lets say this is scaled up to 50,000+ users and 500,000+ blogposts. If I wanted to find a blogpost by a user, which would be a better approach (in terms of performance and code readability):

`Approach 1:` 
Search through all `BlogPost` to find a matching author = ObjectId.

`Approach 2:` 
Search for only the `BlogPost` with ObjectId matching the ObjectId in the `User` `blog_posts` array.

It seems like both approaches would require searching through all 100,000+ records of `BlogPost`. What is the advantage of storing ObjectId in the `User` `blog_posts` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experiences with mongodb is to "avoid" arrays if you can cuz of two things:

- Mongodb storage engines does not like rapidly growing arrays escpecially MMAPv1.
- Its hard to run querys on arrays, especially on nested arrays.

In this case you can totally forgot user.brog_posts so use Approach 1.
It will be faster and easier to run queries on BlogPost.author cuz you will not have to use aggregation framework and you can use indexes more efficiently on a single object then on an array.

All in all, if you use Approach 1 it will be faster and less harder to use.

Comment: Thats good, I was hoping that would be the case. Do you have any other tips on how I should structure MongoDB? Ive read around for best practices but definately feel like I could use more.

Comment: Just avoid deeply nested arrays as much as possible. You are doing the structures right if you can cover your queries 100% with indexes. For an example you can't index nested arrays which is bad... Try to create more documents instead of nesting. Try to avoid relations but its not forbidden aggregation $lookup is pretty fast actually. Basically mongodb queries are pretty fun to use. If you are having pain querying  then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!